# Rails 4: 'redirect_to current_thing' undefined error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a model “Thing,” each of which has_many “Comments,” each of which in turn has_many “Votes.” I want to be able to vote on comments on the Thing show page. This is what I have so far:

Comments Controller:

```
def votecomment
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  Vote.create!(voteable_id: params[:id], voteable_type: 'Comment')
  redirect_to current_thing
end
```

Things View:

```
<%= link_to “Vote”, vote_comment_path(:id => comment.id), method: :post %>
```

Routes:

```
post 'comments/:id/vote' => 'comments#vote', as: 'vote_comment'
```

But I'm getting back this error:

```
NameError in CommentsController#votecomment 
undefined local variable or method `current_thing' for #<CommentsController:0x007f98efa69c00>
```

I tried moving the method to the Things controller, but I got the exact same type of error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `redirect_to @comment.thing`

Comment: How did you come up with `current_thing` ?

Comment: Can you post your code for `current_thing` in your controller

Comment: @Santosh Ah, that works perfectly! Thank you. I saw a bunch of answers where current_user worked, so I assumed current_thing would also work.

Comment: Glad that it worked. I've added it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the following relation in comment.rb

```
belongs_to :thing
```

You can access the thing object of a comment using `@comment.thing`. Since redirect_to accepts objects, you can do

```
redirect_to @comment.thing
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand that nothing is called current_thing if you are familiar with devise and you see ex current_user this is a method in the gem not a populated method with each model you create.

So if you want something like that add method to your application_controller or even application helper to get current_thing

```
def current_thing
  Thing.find() --> or whatever the way you get that current thing.
end
```